# Thread running in debug mode, but doesn't work in real time

Tags: java, multithreading

I've written server app, which works on few threads. We have networking thread to connect and exchange data with client app, dataBaseConnector thread, which connect with sqlite data base, and userInterface thread, which is for simple control of the program.

Main:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9000);
    DataContainer dataContainer = new DataContainer();
    DataBaseConnector dataBaseConnector = new DataBaseConnector(dataContainer);
    UserInterface userInterface = new UserInterface(dataBaseConnector, dataContainer);
    Thread userInterfaceThread = new Thread(userInterface);
    Thread dataBaseConnectorThread = new Thread(dataBaseConnector);
    userInterfaceThread.start();
    dataBaseConnectorThread.start();
    while(dataContainer.workingStatus){
        new Thread(new Handler(new Networking(dataContainer, serverSocket.accept()))).start();
    }
}
}
```

User Interface:

```
public class UserInterface implements Runnable {

private final String WELCOME = "Witaj w programie Auction House! Jest to serwer aplikacji";
private final String MENU = "Menu:";
private final String OPTION_ONE = "1. Zapisz dane do bazy";
private final String OPTION_TWO = "2. Zamknij serwer";
private final String OPTION_THREE = "3. Przywroc menu";
private DataBaseConnector dataBaseConnector;
private DataContainer dataContainer;
private int userChoice = 0;

public UserInterface(DataBaseConnector dataBaseConnector, DataContainer dataContainer) {
    this.dataBaseConnector = dataBaseConnector;
    this.dataContainer = dataContainer;
    setUpMenu();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (dataContainer.workingStatus){
        getUserChoice();
        makeUserRequest();
    }
}

private void setUpMenu() {
    System.out.println(WELCOME);
    System.out.println(MENU);
    System.out.println(OPTION_ONE);
    System.out.println(OPTION_TWO);
    System.out.println(OPTION_THREE);
}

private void getUserChoice() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    userChoice = scanner.nextInt();
}

private void makeUserRequest() {
    switch (userChoice) {
    case 1: {
        dataContainer.lockTheLock();
        dataContainer.checkPoint = true;
        dataContainer.unlockTheLock();
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        dataContainer.lockTheLock();
        dataContainer.workingStatus = false;
        dataContainer.unlockTheLock();
        break;
    }
    case 3: {
        setUpMenu();
        break;
    }
    }
}
}
```

1 - is for writing data into Data Base
2 - is for shutting down server
3 - is for printing menu again

and DataBaseConnector (short version):

```
public DataBaseConnector(DataContainer dataContainer) {
    getJDBCDriverClass();
    connection = connectToDataBase();
    statement = createStatement();
    this.dataContainer = dataContainer;
    createTables();
    selectDataFromDataBase();
    updateDataContainer();
    clearLists();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (dataContainer.workingStatus) {
        if (dataContainer.checkPoint) {
            dataContainer.lockTheLock();
            dropTables();
            createTables();
            setClientList();
            setAuctionList();
            setItemList();
            instertDataIntoDataBase();
            dataContainer.checkPoint = false;
            dataContainer.unlockTheLock();
        }
    }
}
```

And the lock:

```
public class Lock {
private boolean isLocked = false;

public synchronized void lock() throws InterruptedException {
    while (isLocked) {
        wait();
    }
    isLocked = true;
}

public synchronized void unlock() {
    isLocked = false;
    notifyAll();
    try {
        wait(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

And the problem: When running in debug mode in eclipse, everything works fine, but in real time when i'm choosing 1 in console nothing is happening, but when choosing 3, the menu prints again.

Answer (score 0):

When you work in Eclipse, the program is on your computer, but when you work on a network there may be a problem on firewall of network. Check that the 9000 port that uses the socket is open on the firewall, of course only in the network in which you use it.

Comment: yeah mate, but it's simple J2SE app, socket is running great, but the problem is with data base, when chosing 1 from user menu the program freezes, and dataBase connector simply don't work, but in debug it works fine.